# How to kill a c++ .exe file that I made

Tags: windows-10, c++

`1328D carousel.exe` is the file I want to kill. Actually it is a program for a simple question which I wrote. But somehow, it's stuck (in an infinite loop probably). When my computer stopped responding and froze for many seconds, and again started working, I deleted the cpp file (in panic). Now, I cannot delete the .exe file as it says `access denied` . I can't kill the process again because `open in 1328D carousel.exe`. And my pc is suffering since this happened (it freezes, has slowed down immensely). [image: see my task manager] [image: unable to terminate process][image: unable to delete]

How should I deal with the problem. I have no problem if this file gets deleted or changed I just want my pc back in good health.

Comment: Also to note, I've tried rebooting, which didn't help. The process still continues to run.

Comment: Unless you have put that executable somewhere it runs at startup a reboot should have killed it. Open a command prompt and type `shutdown /r /t 0` and check after it has restarted then.

Comment: From the command line (as admin) try `taskkill /PID ##### /F` where ##### is the PID number of the process. If unsuccessful, ry starting the machine in safe mode with command prompt. Then go that folder and delete the file.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio cmd says ERROR: The process with PID 15236 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks!!!!! I wrote that code on cmd after the restart that program wasn't in the running programs list. I quickly deleted that damn program. I was very scared about my pc as I could not get it fixed due to coronavirus. But thanks to you !

Comment: @shoelace glad to help. I have converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have put that executable somewhere it runs at startup a reboot *should* have killed it.

Open a command prompt and type `shutdown /r /t 0` and check after it has restarted then.

It may be that either the reboot you did was using the Windows Fast Startup feature to restart it, or if you did a shutdown and restart, not actually closing it in the first place as it appear to be unkillable by normal means. "Shutdown" from the start menu does not fully close down your machine any more so a runaway process such as this one may not be ended.

The `shutdown` command line should bypass all the "smart" features in Windows and perform a **clean** reboot.